# How do you figure out the dissociation energy for ions?

Tags: homework, bond, ions, enthalpy

Specifically $\ce{KF}$ into the $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{F-}$ ions. I can find tables on the DE into atoms, but where would I go to find the DE between ions?

I am also given that the bond length is 2.17e-10m. Can I use that at all?

Comment: Wait a second... I think I just figured it out! I just use Coulomb's Law, correct?

Comment: And then multiply by distance. That would return energy.

Comment: you would have to integrate Fdx because the force changes as you move the ions apart

Comment: So it wouldn't be as simple as saying the attractive force * bond length = energy of the bond, and the opposite of that would be the dissociation energy?

Comment: no because the attractive force is not constant as the ions are separated. however, integrating the force over the distance with appropriate limits would give you a rough estimate of the bond energy

Comment: also what exactly are you trying to find. the dissociation energy for a gaseous $\ce{KF}$ molecule or the negative of the lattice energy

Comment: I assume gaseous, but I don't really know the difference. I'm taking MIT's OCW 5.111 (Freshman Chem.). The answer key says that the energy required to break the bond is just the opposite of energy of the bond. I understand the force integral, but it also makes sense that the energy stored in a bond would be equivalent to the energy required to break the bond. I thought that was how enthalpy was determined!

Comment: Maybe it is lattice energy... Neither the question nor the answer says anything about it one way or another!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find the heterolytic dissociation energy for a gaseous $\ce{KF}$ molecule then as a rough estimate you can model the ions as point charges and calculate the energy required to separate them from their equilibrium separation (the bond length) to infinity, using Coulomb's Law: $$E = -\int_{2.17\times10^{-10}}^\infty\frac{Qq}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}dr$$

Note that modelling the ions as point charges is a major simplification and so this is probably not a very accurate estimate. Unfortunately I can't find any data for the actual energy so I can't say how accurate this is.

Comment: Okay, awesome. You're right; it is a simplification, but since it's for freshman chemistry, it's probably good enough. So that would be kQq/2r for each atom, so the whole bond energy would be twice that. Thus, kQq/r. So I guess we were saying the same thing!

Comment: when you integrate the function shown you get $\frac{Qq}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$ which equals the bond energy when evaluated between the limits shown. not sure where your thing about energies for each atom is coming from?

Comment: That is the integral of the force on *one* ion. There are two. So you have to double it. Or at least that's my understanding.

Comment: no this is the integral of the force between two charged objects with respect to distance which equals the work done in separating the two charges

Comment: Wait, you're totally right. I just did the integral incorrectly, and then used some mental gymnastics to fit it into what I knew the correct answer to be. The negative indefinite integral equals +kQq/r. Edit: I can't see LaTeX in comments on mobile, so I couldn't see what you wrote before.